# Array forEach() vs reduce()

Tags: javascript, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

what do you think is the best way to do ?

Reduce Way :

```
const result = Object.keys(params).reduce(
      (previous, key) => {
        if (this.model.hasOwnProperty(key)) previous[key] = this.model[key](params[key]);
        return previous;
  }, {});
```

ForEach Way:

```
const result = {};
Object.keys(params).forEach(key => {
      if (this.model.hasOwnProperty(key)) result[key] = this.model[key](params[key]);
    });
```

I'm using airbnb eslint and it doesn't like the reduce way since I modify `previous` (no-param-reassign)

Comment: both of your approaches return the same result?

Comment: yes they do, it's just about the syntax ! :)

Comment: if you don't need to "roll up" an array values - use `forEach` function

Comment: What do you think about @naomik anwser then ?

Comment: Since you are asking about ES6, `.forEach` is effectively deprecated by `for … of`.

Comment: Maybe but since I follow airbnb : 
https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#iterators-and-generators

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the `reduce` is a lot nicer because it doesn't spill vars all over the place. You could make it a little better yet, imo.

```
var result = Object.keys(params).reduce((res,k)=>
  this.model.hasOwnProperty(k)
    ? Object.assign(res, {[k]: this.model[k](params[k])})
    : res, {});
```

Comment: Ah, `Object.assign` seems to be an effective way of working around the linter :-)

Comment: Use spread operator instead of object.assign

Comment: @skone you can use object spread *syntax* if you want, but since it's not supported in most environments, I don't recommend it unless your project already has a transpile step

Comment: makes sense. ....