# Array of objects with custom keys

Tags: javascript

I have an array of strings with vehicle names.

```
a=['car', 'scooter', 'bike'];
```

I need to generate a array such that each object would have a property `color:red` in it

I used `array.reduce` for it. This is the code i have written

```
function getInitialMap(a) {
    const vehicleMap = [];
    return vehicles.reduce((_vehicleMap, type) => {
        _vehicleMap.concat({[type]: {color: red}});
        return _vehicleMap;
    }, vehicleMap);
}
```

what I got is:

```
_vehicleMap = [
    0:{car:{color:red}},
    1:{scooter:{color:red}},
    2:{bike:{color:red}}
]
```

what I required:

```
_vehicleMap = [
    car:{color:red},
    scooter:{color:red},
    bike:{color:red},
]
```

Can someone help in generating array with custom keys here

Comment: Your required array is *INVALID*

Comment: you want a array with car names as keys or map with car names as keys?

Comment: You can use `Object.assign(...keys.map(vehicle => ({[vehicle] : {color: 'red'}})));`

Comment: array with car names with keys

Comment: then create a new array and just push the object `{color:"red"}` using keys. reduce function won't work in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Map by definition is dictionary, it can't be an array. You also don't need reduce for this. Here is how I would do this

```
var a=['car', 'scooter', 'bike'];

var map = {};

a.forEach(function(v) {
  map[v] = {color: 'red'}
})

console.log(map)
```

Comment: What's wrong with reduce?

Comment: nothing but its much more simpler with forEach its literally one line with es6 a.forEach(v => map[v] = {color: 'red'})

Comment: Sure it's kind of simpler. but it's not pure, hence you have to take care of possibly unintended side effects.

Comment: how do you mean? as in the difference between reduce and forEach in this case?

Comment: I mean it in that way, that for the `forEach` approach, you need an extra variable declaration before the actual assignment. See this small discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37461580/array-foreach-vs-reduce

Comment: Still don't understand how it differs in implementation since you have to define the accumulator in reduce as well, however forEach mutates existing object but reduce doesn't so in that case it might be more helpful to use reduce

Answer (score 4):

If you want to do this with `reduce`: this is my solution:

```js
const a = ['car', 'scooter', 'bike'];
const colored = a.reduce((agg, vehicle) => {
  agg[vehicle] = {color: 'red'};
  return agg;
}, {});
console.log(colored);
```